# Simple examples of fractional ideals

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, examples-counterexamples

> Let $K$ be the quotient field of an integral domain $R$. A *fractional ideal* $I$ is a subset of $K$ not $\{0\}$, for which a $0 \neq r \in R$ exists so that $r I \subseteq R$ is an ideal in $R$.

All examples I've found are either very general or complicated. I'm looking for simple examples of fractional ideals.

Wouldn't just be $$I = \biggl\{\ldots, -\frac{15}{7}, -\frac{10}{7}, -\frac{5}{7}, 0, \frac{5}{7}, \frac{10}{7}, \frac{15}{7}, \ldots \biggr\}$$
an example of a fractional ideal with $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $K = \mathbb{Q}$ (because $7 \cdot I = 5 \mathbb{Z}$)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @GerryMyerson: ... and also $\{ \ldots, -\frac{3}{7}, -\frac{2}{7}, -\frac{1}{7}, 0, \frac{1}{7}, \frac{2}{7}, \frac{3}{7}, \ldots \}$, because the "untrue" ideal $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't prohibited...